# Generic types and wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class created with generics in Java and I have several doubts about this:

```
 public class Averias<T, E> {

    private ArrayList<T> averias;
    private E prueba;
    private ArrayList<? extends T> animal;

    public Averias(ArrayList<T> averias, E prueba, ArrayList<? extends T> animal) {
        this.averias = averias;
        this.prueba = prueba;
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getAverias() {
        return averias;
    }

    public void setAverias(ArrayList<T> averias) {
        this.averias = averias;
    }

    public E getPrueba() {
        return prueba;
    }

    public void setPrueba(E prueba) {
        this.prueba = prueba;
    }

    public ArrayList<? extends T> getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(ArrayList<? extends T> animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
}
```

This is my class, and now the first doubt I have is: when I want to use this class, do I have to infer all types or can I use just one?

```
private Averias<Integer, String> averias;
```

If I infer all types works, but I think a lot of code that every time I want to use it, I have to infer the type, then I don't know if there is some simpler way that I don't know.

In the class I have an ArrayList with a wildcard: private ArrayList animal;. I still don't have very clear how wildcards work, I know that it can be put alone, with extensions or with super, and depending on how it works, but I don't know when it would be useful to use them.

Comment: "but I think a lot of code that every time I want to use it" yes. This is a cost of using generics that you have to weigh against the utility.

Comment: Note also that (bounded) wildcards should really only be used to increase flexibility of method *parameters*. Using them in return types is a pain at call sites, because you have to retain the "wildcardedness" in types there. So, if you are worried about the verbosity of including all type parameters already, having to include bounded wildcards in the types makes things even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inference can work, but if you go with inference, it's all or nothing. You can't specify half of the generics parameters and leave the other half inferred. To use inference, you need the diamond operator. For example, given:

```
void foo(Averias<String, Integer> a);
```

you can write:

```
thingie.foo(new Averias<>());
```

and it'll infer the `<String, Integer>` bit. For static methods with type args, you get inference without any additional syntax, so no need for `<>` there.

For fields, inference cannot be used; in `private Averias<Integer, String> averias` it cannot be avoided.

For wildcards:

With generics the inheritance rules are more strict. For example, this:

```
Number x = new Integer(5);
```

is legal java. But if we genericsify this:

```
List<Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

it is *NOT LEGAL* – generics are 'invariant', meaning only if the same thing is on both the left and right side, it'd work. Only `List<Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>()` works. That may strike you as weird, but it is correct: The thing is, with lists, you can also *write* to them. And, you can write a double into a `List<Number>` (after all, a double is a number), but.. a double isn't an integer. Hence why it works like this.

If you NEED covariance, you can still do that, that's where wildcards come in. This IS legal:

```
List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

So what happens with the 'add a double' problem? Easy: You *cannot add anything* to a `List<? extends whatever>`. (Well, except `null` which is always okay).

`super` is for contravariance. The effective notion of `Integer x = new Number`. With contravariance you can add things to a list, but if you `get` from it, you'll always get a type of `Object` out:

```
List<? super Integer> x = new ArrayList<Number>(); // legal
x.add(new Integer(10)); // Okay
x.add(someNumber); // illegal
Object z = x.get(0); // that works; anything other than Object would not
```

`super` is by far the most rare.

Comment: I've been testing examples and if I put: `private ArrayList<Number> numero = new ArrayList<Integer>();` it doesn't work for me, however if I use covariance (it's called that way to the use of extends?) and use: `private ArrayList<? extends Number> numero = new ArrayList<Integer>();` if it works, is this normal?

Comment: @Isaac yes. `ArrayList<? extends Number>` means that every element contained by that list can be cast to `Number`. `ArrayList<Integer>` means that every element in the list can be cast to `Integer`, *but also* that it is safe to add more `Integer`s to it. Since `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, it is safe to use a `ArrayList<? extends Number>` to refer to a `ArrayList<Integer>`; you just can't add anything (except null) to it.

Comment: @Isaac, yes, hence why I put NOT LEGAL in caps and italics. Re-read that section to understand why `ArrayList<Number>` won't work but `ArrayList<? extends Number>` will.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Ah okay, sorry, I understood that this case did work, guilt of being using the translator :) Yes, I understand that it works because when you put extensions, it works with the types that extend Number, as is the case of Integer.